# Are there any scenarios where the 'Dispose Pattern' shouldn't be used on an Object which contains managed and un-managed resources?

Tags: c#, .net, language-design

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.110).aspx#basic_pattern) says that to properly clean up an object which contains managed and un-managed resources, you need to implement the 'Dispose Pattern'.

Given that the class implements the IDisposable interface, and overrides the Object.Finalize() method (has a destructor), **is there any reason why the compiler shouldn't automatically implement the pattern for you?** For instance, compiling:

```
public class Example : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose() {
        //Disposing managed objects implementation
    }

    ~Example() {
        //Disposing unmanaged objects implementation
    }
}
```

As if it were typed as follows:

```
public class Example : IDisposable
{
    private bool previouslyDisposed = false;

    private void CleanResources(bool safeToCleanManagedResources)
    {
        if (!this.previouslyDisposed)
        {
            _finalize();
            if (safeToCleanManagedResources) {
                _dispose();
            }
            this.previouslyDisposed = true;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        CleanResources(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    ~Example() {
        CleanResources(false);
    }

    private void _dispose() {
        //The contents of the Dispose() method are moved here.
    }

    private void _finalize() {
        //The contents of the ~Example() method are moved here.
    }
}
```

From what I understand, this should **always be safe and valid**. I can not think of any scenarios where these rules would need to be broken. I know this isn't the most pressing feature the C# team is working on, but asides from that:

**Are there any scenarios where an object containing managed and un-managed resources wouldn't want to follow the 'Dispose Pattern'?**

I'm talking about the compiler generating a method which functions like `CleanResources()`, and moves the `Dispose()` and `~Example()` methods to anonymous backing methods (similar to how auto-properties generate private backing fields). This would mean that any calls to `Dispose()` or `~Example()` would automatically implement the 'Dispose Pattern'.

Comment: I remember the time when this Dispose pattern was being debated, to solve some very nasty problems in pre-1.0 days. This was the solution they came up with, and I always expected it to be just a temporary stopgap. I hated it then as I hate it now, but I can't convince myself that embedding it in the compiler is any better.

Comment: @david.pfx What would be a better solution then? Genuine question. I don't see any other alternative.

Comment: Add some documentation to your methods first. You might not need to do anything as the users of these method might do the best they know with these resources themselves.

Comment: Some very clever people have thought about that problem and come up with this solution, which has stood essentially unchanged for well over 10 years. All I could really ask now is that the compiler routinely check the implementation of this pattern for correctness and complain loudly, until someone (not me) comes up with something better.

Comment: @david.pfx Interesting. I had not considered a compiler warning/error. I am trying to understand why they made their decision, and after searching for hours and asking this question, I still have no idea. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @randomA I'm looking for specific instances where the dispose pattern shouldn't be used. I thought about it for hours and couldn't think of any scenarios where someone wouldn't want to follow it.

Comment: Not all memory needs to be disposed. Some programs just run and then stop. Phone apps mostly have no need to shut themselves down, the instance just gets deleted.

Comment: @david.pfx I understand. The backing code would only be generated when an object implements IDisposable and overrides Object.Finalize(). In all other scenarios, nothing would change. Given those conditions, it is safe to assume the object contains managed and un-managed resources, and therefore should follow the 'Dispose Pattern'.

Answer (score 2):

Sure.

The core issue with this class is that you're not guaranteeing that the inheritor (which you note is a *severe* drawback) overrides the `DisposeBlahResources`. They should be abstract to enforce usage, and at that point I would question how that's any different/better/safer than implementing `Dispose` for its two cases.

Could resource management be done better? Sure. This though just seems like you're renaming the poop that's already there.

Comment: I'm sorry, how is it just renaming?

Comment: @stephenm - implementing `Dispose` is just as much work as implementing your virtual methods (that should probably be abstract).